# Searching an NSArray full of dictionary objects not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I am trying to search an nsarray with dictionary objects but the array is unchanged even after filtering it with the predicate that I have set up. Thanks in advance for any help at all.

```
 - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self filterArray:searchText];
    NSLog(@"search text changed");
}


- (void)filterArray: (NSString *)searchText
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(userSetname LIKE[cd] %@)", searchText];

    self.originalResults = self.freindResults;
    NSMutableArray *array = self.freindResults;

    [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"Filtered array %@", array);
    self.freindResults = array;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

What I generally have as a dictionary is:

```
"<Freinds:4CXI96JMLU:(null)> {
ID = 4CXI96JMLU;
name = "Kevin Turner";
profilePic = "<PFFile: 0x10a290220>";
user = h6r0fwqau9xzi14ojivjpu9f;
userID = h6r0fwqau9xzi14ojivjpu9f;
userSetname = kevonturner;
}",
"<Freinds:YtTGlssOHv:(null)> {
ID = YtTGlssOHv;    
name = "John Appleseed";
profilePic = "<PFFile: 0x10a265360>";
user = h6r0fwqau9xzi14ojivjpu9f;
userID = ozu5st58546zd6nucn8gzutmo;
userSetname = johnnyy;
}"
```

as outputted in the console

Comment: can you just paste an example of what the dictionary would be generally like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not get filtered data from the array instance that you have.. filteredArrayUsingPredicate will return the filtered array. change the code as follows..

```
- (void)filterArray: (NSString *)searchText
```

{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(userSetname LIKE[cd] %@)", searchText];

```
self.originalResults = self.freindResults;
NSMutableArray *array = self.freindResults;

NSArray *filteredArry = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"Filtered array %@", filteredArry);

self.freindResults = filteredArry;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userSetname = %@",name];

NSArray *filteredArry = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```